# JavaScript callback function with relative variables

Tags: javascript, button, callback

I am not entirely sure how to phrase this question, but basically, I have a class, `button` that on its click should call the function passed to it.

```
button = function(...,callBack) {
    //...
    this._cb = callBack;
}
button.prototype.callBack = function(e) {
    //...
    this._cb();
}
```

and then somewhere else

```
//on canvas click
e.target.callBack(e);
```

(I hope this is about the right amount of background, I can give more if needed)

So the issue I am running into is when I dynamically instantiate the buttons such that their callbacks use data from an array. i.e.

```
for (var i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) {
    buttons[buttons.length] = new button(..., function() {drawLevel(levels[i])});
}
```

Then when they are clicked, they run that callback code and try to find some random value for i (probably a for-loop that didn't use `var`) and runs that level.

My question is, how can I (without using eval) circumvent this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really get what you ask. But one thing to note, `function() {drawLevel(levels[i])}` will have `levels.length` for `i` for all buttons when `this._cb()` is called, because of how scoping in js works.

Comment: Right, and that is my problem. I need a way to call the function so that it draws whatever was located at `levels[i]` instead of going out and pulling `levels[i]` for whatever `i` it has

Comment: You should read a little bit about how scoping in js works, and what meaning the `var` statement has. Unlike other languages, js does not have block level scopes, only function level, and another _anomaly_ is that it does not matte where (on the level of the function) the `var varName;` exists: `function() {i=1; var i;}` has the same effect as writing `function() {var i; i=1;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking, but it looks like you're going to be getting the wrong value for i in the anonymous function you're creating in the loop (it will always be levels.length)

Way around this is to have a different scope for every function created, with the i in each scope being a copy of the i in the loop

```
buttons[buttons.length] = new button(..., (function(i){ 
    return function() {drawLevel(levels[i])};
})(i));
```

Comment: One note `i` will be `levels.length` not `levels.length - 1`